# how to add a new association to library model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, merit-gem

I am using merit library in rails. And hope to add an association in Merit::Score::Point so that it has a has_one association with another model call ScoreWorkflow.

Below is my code. In this code, I hope to add an association so that I can add a has_one to the library model. However it does not work. Is there anything that like this that I can put some function/assoication to a library model. Thanks.

```
module Merit
  module Score
    class Point < Point
      has_one :score_workflow
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ScoreWorkflow
      belongs_to :point
end
```

If you want it the other way around...

```
module Merit
  module Score
    class Point < Point
      belongs_to :score_workflow
    end
  end
end
```

... and...

```
class ScoreWorkflow
      has_one :point
end
```

Sometimes you must specify the class names:

```
module Merit
  module Score
      class Point < Point
        has_one :score_workflow, :class_name => "ScoreWorkflow"
      end
  end
end


class ScoreWorkflow
    belongs_to :point, :class_name => "Merit::Score::Point"
end
```

Also make sure to check your foreign keys if you use ActiveRecord, so they match the conventions.

Comment: Actually, this is what I did. And it is not work because of the Merit::Score::Point in the lib override my Point model in model folder. So how can I make rails using my model rather than libs model?